# run maven java project using batch file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-batch

I've a java application in which I'm using maven to load dependencies. My main method is in App.java  and there are various other classes. This is a spring based application.
I've to run this application using batch file.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. made a manifest file to give  main class name
2. generated a jar of application
3. in a lib folder placed all the jars which my app uses
4. in manifest gave all the jars path

But I want to know if there is any other way I can achieve the same thing. Here in manifest I've to give all the jars names

Also in application jar, a manifest file is automatically created. So I've to manually edit it to give main class name and all dependent jars.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503047/maven-running-created-jar-file-with-depedencies/27503250#27503250

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Maven Jar Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) to do what you want. You can configure it to place all your manifest entries to meet your needs.

```
<plugin>
    <!-- jar plugin -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>package.path.for.App</Main-Class>
                <implementation-version>1.0</implementation-version>            
            </manifestEntries>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>  <!-- use this to specify a classpath prefix, in your case, lib -->
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To facilitate copying all your dependencies to a particular folder, use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
    <!-- copy all dependencies of your app to target folder-->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory> <!-- use this field to specify where all your dependencies go -->
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan. Is there anyway that I can get all the jars also automatically added into some folder, lets say lib. As otherwise I've to manually copy each jar from my repository and put in lib folder.

Comment: Thanks :) you have been a great help.